# CSS: How to set button position to the right of a html table

Tags: html, css

I have an html table whose columns are dynamically generated via Ajax calls and Jquery. Hence the width of the table is not fixed.

I want to have buttons on the top and bottom of the table that are right-aligned only to the table width.

If I do just a `float: right;` -> my buttons get aligned to the extreme right hand side of the page.

If I do `margin: 40px 0 0 620px;` -> My buttons get aligned to the right of a specific table, with a specific width.

However that is not my goal.

currently my CSS looks like this:

```
// Button at the top of the table //
.BackBtn
{
    margin: 40px 0 0 620px;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
}

// Table itself //
table {
    border:none;
    margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

// Confirm button //
.button{
   padding:25px 500px 0 950px;  
   width:240px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ama3123d/3/

The jsfiddle doesn't show any table, because the table is dynamically created via an Ajax call to a webmethod, and then jquery to parse information and created columns and populate values.

Comment: "*The jsfiddle doesn't show any table, because the table is dynamically created via an Ajax call...*" - consider showing a table that contains representative data in order that we have something to work with that somewhat resembles your actual code, which also helps with meeting your requirements for the positioning of the buttons. Incidentally, the easiest way would be to wrap the table in a parent element, and add the button elements as siblings, at which point `float: right` should take them only to the right of the wrapping element, assuming that the wrapper collapses to the table's width.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified solution would be, to make a wrapper element that is set to `display: inline-block;` to be just as wide as the containing table. Now you can set `text-align: right;` to align your button elements horizontally. To apply that to your specific case, you have to give us your exact markup with an example of your generated table.

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>top</button>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button>bottom</button>
</div>
```